# How to find the first and list point of an impulse in a RIR?

Tags: python, impulse-response

I'm looking for a simple algorithm where given a RIR sample file I can find the beginning of the impulse and the last point of the tail.

If possible, would love to implement it in python.

Comment: Could you specify what the first and last point of an impulse would be to you? Is the first point the peak, or some sample before it? How is the last point of an impulse defined, is it the point where its amplitude (envelope) touches the zero line? You should try to be more descriptive of your problem and clarify things, otherwise people won't be able to help you with your problem.

Comment: Is that a measured or a simulated room impulse response ?

Comment: @Hilmar , seems to me that if it's simulated impulse response then we would know from the simulator when the first reflection arrives.  If it's the measured output of a simulator, then it's the same problem as a measured room impulse response.

Comment: With simulated response you can start looking for zeros. Measured responses tend to have a fair bit of noise which makes this more tricky

Comment: Its from a simulated room impulse indeed.
I want to use the RIR for a convolutional reverb. So the first and last point should encompass the impulse.